# Have a trouble with typescript compiler after updating VS 2015 to Update 3

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

Having an error on build the solution "tsc.exe exited with code 2". It seems that Typescript compiler is not found, what possible solutions can be suggested?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: the problem was solved by adding some code from official site of typescript in .xproj

Comment: "solved by adding some code" isn't very helpful to anyone else running into this issue....